# Fix Text in <div>, prevent moving after calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem:** I have 2 divs in a td-Tag, where the Text inside is moving positions, but shouldn't.

Div Code:

```
    <tr>
        <td id="mehlSumme">
            <div id="mehlSumme2">Noch zu berechnen</div>
            <div id="mehl">Mehl</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I update the data in the div-id="mehlSumme2" with jQuery and the text is moving afterwards.

I can't get the text in mehlSumme2 right-bound fixed and mehl left-bound fixed.

I tried the following:

```
       #mehlSumme2, #zuckerSumme2, #butterSumme2, #quarkSumme2, #fuellungButterSumme2, #fuellungZuckerSumme2, #eierSumme2, #bananenSumme2, #apfelSumme2 {
        text-align: inherit;
        font-size: 70%;
        display: inline;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    #mehl, #zucker, #butter, #quark, #fuellungButter, #fuellungZucker, #fuellungEier, #bananen, #apfel {
        text-align: inherit;
        font-size: 70%;
        display: inline;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

But this doesn't get me any further.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the div has display:inline and you make the text inside shorter, the div shrinks. Is that the problem? If so, do you know what the width should be? I mean, I don't see an attempt to keep the width constant in the code.

Comment: the width of the td is 400px and doesn't shrink. I don't have specified the width of the div, i don't think it's needed. I just need the "mehl" text to stay where it is after i update from "Noch zu berechnen" to the actual amount of mehl needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the `text-align: inherit` bit. This will, for #mehlSumme2 and #mehl, make them have the text alignment from the parent (td).

You also have `padding-right` on the element that needs to be right-aligned. And `padding-left` for the element that needs to be left-aligned. `padding: left` adds space on the left of the element, so it effectively pushes the contents to the right boundary. (Same for `padding: right`.) Maybe if you switch them, you can make it look like what you want at least.

Another attempt would be adding `text-align` with `:left` or `:right` for those corresponding elements. Although, `text-align` is not very widely used since flex-box. And `<td>`s are not widely used either.

EDIT: I added `inline-block` to your display property in the all the ids that have 2 after after them. It seems to not make the changing section shrink. Also, the code you posted did not work for the jQ. You just forgot to close the function properly.

Comment: text-align:left and :right switches the text, badly, after the text gets updated from "Noch zu berechnen" to the actual amount of the receipe. I need it fixed after i update it.

Comment: Do you have a snippet or fiddle you can post along with a way to update the text so I can see what you mean?